# java - Selenium Chromedriver can't find element by LinkText but Geckodriver does

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

So the element I want to click on is located here:

```
<li class=" ">
    <a href="google.de">
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-profile"></i>&nbsp;
        <span class="menu-item-parent ">Mein Konto</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Now I have the following Java Code set up:

```
WebElement konto = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Mein Konto')]"));
```

and

```
WebElement konto1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Mein Konto"));
```

But in the Chrome Driver it can't locate the element:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Mein Konto"}

The xpath works fine, but for my tester team linktext would be easier to use, so I am trying to use that instead of xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM is like that,

```
<a href="google.de">
  <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-profile"></i>&nbsp;
    <span class="menu-item-parent ">Mein Konto</span>
</a>
```

Just 'Mein Konto' is not only link text. It will be partial link text as `&nbsp` is also there. My suggestion is to use partial link text.

```
driver.findelement(By.partialLinkText("Mein Konto"));
```

EDIT :

I want to highlight Anderson's comment

Presence of whitespaces in link text is not a reason to use search by `partialLinkText`. Just copy link text from rendered web page (not from Chrome dev console) and pass to `By.linkText()`. It might looks like `driver.findElement(By.linkText(" Mein Konto"))`;. But if you sure that there are no other links on page with Mein Konto substring, then `By.partialLinkText` is OK.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed explanation of the cause and the fix.

Comment: @DominikL. , FYI presence of whitespaces in link text is not a reason to use search by `partialLinkText`. Just copy link text from *rendered webpage* (not from *Chrome dev console*) and pass to `By.linkText()`. It might looks like `driver.findElement(By.linkText("  Mein Konto"));`. But if you sure that there are no other links on page with `Mein Konto` substring, then `By.partialLinkText` is OK

Answer (score 0):

The `<span>` element is containing the text 'Mein Konto'

if your element is `<a href='#'>Mein Konto</a>` then you can find it with By.linkText();

Here you can find more info how to locator is working:

https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/how-to-locate-element-by-link-text-and-partial-link-text-locator/

Comment: Hi there, what exactly do you mean by this answer? I cannot quite understand what it is you have suggesting to change. Thanks

Comment: I have corrected the formatting of replay. 
Main point is that you cannot find a text with locator By.linkText since the text is wrapped in a <span> tag. As others suggested you can use the By.partialLinkText() visit the link i have provided for more information.

Answer (score 0):

linkText method matches exactly text appears on the page. It is not matching exactly may be because of browser rendering issue. 
You can try with Parital link text.

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for you answer. With you suggested change I've got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'Mein Konto' is not all of your LinkText, but inside a `<span>` Element, you cannot use `By.linkText();`, because `&nbsp` is added. In that case you use `By.PartialLinkText();` to locate the element.